How to modify query run based on the day of the week?
I have code that runs every weekday looking for the previous day, however, on Mondays, it needs to look from last Friday through Sunday. Right now, I am manually commenting in and out rows of code if it's a Monday. How can I have it combined without having to touch it every Monday? I use placeholders to declare dates that will be used further down the code. I am using SQL Server.
/* If today *is not* MONDAY, then use lines 2&3; if today *is* MONDAY, use lines 4&5 */
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE = getdate()-1         
DECLARE @PREV15STARTDATE DATE = getdate()-15
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE = getdate()-3      
DECLARE @PREV15STARTDATE DATE = getdate()-17

Later on, I will have a select statement that uses the following:
where ACTIVITY_CREATE_DATE_TIME between @PREV15STARTDATE and @STARTDATE

Which dbms are you using? (getdate() is a product specific function.)

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Does this answer your question? Get day of week in SQL Server 2005/2008

SSMS is only a UI, the database engine is called SQL server. And the relevant version is select @@version

Using case test if today is a Monday and if it is add -2 days to startdate

Note: you shouldn't use -15 to add days, you should use dateadd.

Microsoft SQL Server 2017

You might also want to think about what you want to happen if the code is accidentally run on a weekend (or you later make it so).
